# Http redirect in Tomcat or web service proxy

Tags: web-services, tomcat, redirect, proxy, url-mapping

I got a web service running on *127.0.0.1:8080/test/mywebservice*

This web service (port:8080) is created dynamically by another web service (port:80) that is hosted in Tomcat. All web services that are created by Tomcat directly can use port 80, however, not those that are created dynamically.

I have to do this since I need to share objects between these two web services.

The problem is that the client can only make requests to port 80, and I can't host my web service on port 80.

Does anyone know how to redirect requests to
    *127.0.0.1:**80**/test/mywebservice*
  to
    *127.0.0.1:**8080**/test/mywebservice*

Answer (score 1):

Use web server like nginx or apache

[Configuration example](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample2)

You need install nginx by default and nginx.conf should contain this:

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
listen       80;
server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

# pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
location / {
  proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

}

This congiguration let nginx listen port 80 and redirect all requests to http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Could you please give me some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, I got it working. Below is how I did it in Apache.
Add the following lines into Apache's httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test/mywebservice
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible unless there is another service listening on port 80.  You could run the web service on port 80 instead of port 8080.